# How to pass two viewmodel data to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Actually its not two viewmodel in my case only one but I am trying to pass a single value of product and then a list of products below is my controller so you can understand better

```
      public ActionResult Filter(long? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
//select a single product
                ProductViewModel products = new ProductViewModel();
                var pro = db.Products.Find(id);

                if (pro != null)
                {
                    products.ProductId = pro.ProductId;
                    products.ProductName = pro.ProductName;
                    products.AddDate = pro.AddDate;
                    products.ApplicationUserId = pro.ApplicationUserId;
                    products.ProductDescription = pro.ProductDescription;
                    products.ProductPictures = db.ProductPictures.Where(m => m.ProductId == id).ToList();



                }


               //Now creating list 

                ProductViewModel product = new ProductViewModel();
                var pictures = db.ProductPictures;
                var model = db.Products.Where(p=>p.ApplicationUserId==User.Identity.GetUserId()).Select(p => new ProductViewModel
                {
                    ProductId = p.ProductId,
                    ProductName = p.ProductName,
                    ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription,
                    ProductPictures = pictures.Where(x => x.ProductId == p.ProductId),
                    Category = p.Category,
                    AddDate = p.AddDate,
                    ApplicationUserId = p.ApplicationUserId,

                });


                return View(model);
            }
```

but how can i pass both values to the view i tried viewbag for single product as

```
  ViewBag.ProductId = pro.ProductId;
                    ViewBag.ProductName = pro.ProductName;
                    ViewBag.AddDate = pro.AddDate;
                    ViewBag.ApplicationUserId = pro.ApplicationUserId;
                    ViewBag.ProductDescription = pro.ProductDescription;
                    ViewBag.ProductPictures = db.ProductPictures.Where(m => m.ProductId == id).ToList();

                    ViewBag.idd = pro.ProductId;
```

but dont know how to get value of list Viewbag.productpicture in razor view. and is it good way to pass value using viewbag or is there any other method??

Comment: Create a view model with 2 properties `ProductViewModel Product` and `IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> ProductList` and return that to the view

Comment: Thanks again stephan , post this in answer so i can mark it as answer.

Comment: Answer added to address the question, but your code suggests you might be wanting to edit one `Product` and on the same page also display a list of all `Product`, in which case this might not be the best solution.

Comment: No i am not going to edit  but selection of product and creating a combo pack..... for edit i think partial view will be the best solution right??

Comment: OK (was not sure what you were trying to achieve) For an edit view, you just need to return a single `ProductViewModel`

Comment: Hmmm not sure how to do it using single (list and editable one on same page), will ask another question if its necessary in project ... but thanks a lot for the answers ... will show you the project once its done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model containing properties for the object and collection of objects, for example

```
public CombinedProductVM
{
  public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, initialize a new instance and set the properties

```
CombinedProductVM model = new CombinedProductVM
{
  Product = // your first query above
  ProductList = // your second query above
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view use `@model CombinedProductVM`